# using GITLAB GUI web interface, what is the equivalent of push for a file?

Tags: gitlab

What is the equivalent of "push" action used across command line, when somebody wants to use only the Gitlab web interface, on a branch ? Is it the "replace" item available in sub-menu viewable when clicking on the file ?

Comment: What is wrong with command line?

Comment: the person is not confortable with command line. she wants to use gitlab only accross GUI web interface.